# How to use image url stored in Firestore

Tags: html, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have an image uploaded to Firestore storage which I want to display on my website. I am then storing the url for this image in my Firestore document:

[image]

I can successfully reference the data for this document and all the others in the collection, then display in my html as so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="infinite | async as products">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100" (scrolledIndexChange)="nextBatch($event, (products[products.length - 1].data.productName))">
        <div class="product-row" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center center">  
            <div fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" fxFlex.gt-md="30%" *cdkVirtualFor="let p of products; let i = index; trackByIndex">
                    <mat-card class="product-tile">
                        <img class="product-thumbnail" src="p.data.thumbnail" [routerLink]="p.id">
                        <div class="product-brand">
                            {{ p.id }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <span id="product-name">{{ p.data.productName }}</span> <span id="product-price">{{ p.data.price }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-to-pad-button">
                            <button (click)="openDialog(p.id)" mat-raised-button color="accent">Add to Pad</button>
                            <a href="p.link" class="mat-raised-button color=accent">Click Me</a>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ng-container>
```

In theory, I would assume that calling the reference to thumbnail, which is the image URL, would result in the image being displayed. However, the result is:

[image]

Am I incorrectly referencing the image URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change p.data.thumbnail to {{ p.data.thumbnail }}

Comment: Perfect, works exactly as intended now - thank you. I should have guessed this but assumed it worked like a string.